# How to draw the following special table in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't know How to draw the following special table in tikz?
I know some elementary commands of tikz but I am confused! Any suggest are appreciate.

**UPDATE:** WME:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--(0,10)--(10,10)--(10,0)--(0,0);
    \draw (0,1)--(10,1);
    \draw (0,2)--(10,2);
    \draw (0,3)--(10,3);
    \draw (0,4)--(10,4);
    \draw (0,5)--(10,5);
    \draw (0,6)--(10,6);
    \draw (0,7)--(10,7);
    \draw (0,8)--(10,8);
    \draw (0,9)--(10,9);
    %---------------------
    \draw (1,0)--(1,10);
    \draw (2,0)--(2,10);
    \draw (3,0)--(3,10);
    \draw (4,0)--(4,10);
    \draw (5,0)--(5,10);
    \draw (6,0)--(6,10);
    \draw (7,0)--(7,10);
    \draw (8,0)--(8,10);
    \draw (9,0)--(9,10);
    %------------------------

    \draw[very thick](0,10)--(10,10)--(10,0)--(0,0)--(0,9)-- (9,9)--(9,1)--        (1,1)--(1,8)--(8,8)--(2,8)--(8,8)--(8,2)--(2,2)--(2,7)--(7,7)--(7,3)--(3,3)--(3,6)   --(6,6)--(6,4)--(4,4)--(4,5)   --(5,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at chapter 20, Matrices and Alignment in the pgf manual, http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf . In particular, it specifies access to the corners and edges of a `tikz` matrix

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you've tried to do so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution uses the [spiral code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706260/3365346) which I translated to lua with some modification.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[step=1,very thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

  % position numbers
  \begin{luacode}
    function isPrime(n)
      primes = {}
      if n <= 0 then
        return false
      end
      if n <= 2 then
        return true
      end
      if n % 2 == 0 then
        return false
      end
      for i = 3,n/2,2 do
        if n % i == 0 then
          return false
        end
      end
      return true
    end

    NUM = 100
    di = 1
    dj = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    segment_passed = 0
    segment_length = 1
    for k=0, (NUM-1) do
      if isPrime(k+1) then
        tex.sprint("\\draw ("..(i-0.5)..","..(j-0.5)..") -- ("..(i+0.5)..","..(j+0.5)..");")
        tex.sprint("\\draw ("..(i-0.5)..","..(j+0.5)..") -- ("..(i+0.5)..","..(j-0.5)..");")
        tex.sprint("\\draw node at ("..i..","..j..") {\\colorbox{white}{"..(k+1).."}};")
      else
        tex.sprint("\\draw node at ("..i..","..j..") {"..(k+1).."};")
      end
      i = i + di
      j = j + dj
      segment_passed = segment_passed + 1

      if segment_passed == segment_length then
        segment_passed = 0
        tmp = di
        di = -dj
        dj = tmp
        if dj == 0 then
          segment_length = segment_length + 1
        end
      end
    end
  \end{luacode}

  % draw spiral
  \begin{luacode}
    NUM = 120
    di = -1
    dj = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    segment_passed = 0
    segment_length = 1
    for k=0, (NUM-1) do
      tex.sprint("\\draw[ultra thick,line cap=round] ("..(i+0.5)..","..(j+0.5)..") -- ")
      i = i + di
      j = j + dj
      tex.sprint("("..(i+0.5)..","..(j+0.5)..");")
      segment_passed = segment_passed + 1

      if segment_passed == segment_length then
        segment_passed = 0
        tmp = di
        di = -dj
        dj = tmp
        if dj == 0 then
          segment_length = segment_length + 1
        end
      end
    end
  \end{luacode}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**
I figured out that the sketch may belong to the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral). Thus, the diagonal lines in case of some prime numbers should indicate the diagonal lines within such a spiral.

Just for fun, I adapted my example code to generate the figure similar to the Wikipedia article. (I'll hope it is not too much off topic)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.05]
  % position circles
  \begin{luacode}
    function isPrime(n)
      primes = {}
      if n <= 0 then
        return false
      end
      if n <= 2 then
        return true
      end
      if n % 2 == 0 then
        return false
      end
      for i = 3,n/2,2 do
        if n % i == 0 then
          return false
        end
      end
      return true
    end

    NUM = 40000
    di = 1
    dj = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    segment_passed = 0
    segment_length = 1
    for k=0, (NUM-1) do
      if isPrime(k+1) then
        tex.sprint("\\filldraw ("..i..","..j..") circle (0.3);")
      else
        -- tex.sprint("\\draw node at ("..i..","..j..") {"..(k+1).."};")
      end
      i = i + di
      j = j + dj
      segment_passed = segment_passed + 1

      if segment_passed == segment_length then
        segment_passed = 0
        tmp = di
        di = -dj
        dj = tmp
        if dj == 0 then
          segment_length = segment_length + 1
        end
      end
    end
  \end{luacode}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that not all prime number are crossed out. What is the algorithm behind that?

Comment: +1 for the effort. Some boxes are struck out though.

Comment: hzhr, Thanks for your patient and good answer.

Answer (score 3):

To help you along....

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,10}
      {
      \draw(0,\x)--(10,\x);
      \draw(\x,0)--(\x,10);
      }
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (0,10)--(10,10);
   \foreach \x in {9,7,...,1} 
     {
     \draw[ultra thick,red] (0.5*\x+5.5,0.5*\x+5.5)--(0.5*\x+5.5,4.5-0.5*\x)--(4.5-0.5*\x,4.5-0.5*\x)
       -- (4.5-0.5*\x,4.5+0.5*\x) -- (4.5+0.5*\x,4.5+0.5*\x);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Shame on me, I didn't recognize the prime numbers !

This is my first LuaLatex attempt. Bit of a weird language, isn't it ?

### The output

[image]

### The `lua`

```
--- makeMatrix.lua
function zeroTable(n)
  myTable={}
  for i=1,n do
    myTable[i]={}
    for j=1,n do
      myTable[i][j] = "0"
    end 
  end 
  return myTable
end

myListCrossed = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
isCrossed ={}
for key,value in pairs(myListCrossed) do
  isCrossed[value]=true
end

function nodeContent(a)
  if isCrossed[a] then
    option="|[crossed]| "
  else
    option=""
  end
  return option .. a
end

function table(n)
  myTable=zeroTable(n)
  square=math.floor(n^2)
  back=false
  vertical=false
  dir={}
  dir[1]=1
  dir[2]=0
  a=square-1
  myTable[1][1]=square
  i=1
  j=1
  repeat
    repeat
      i=i+dir[1]
      j=j+dir[2]
      myTable[i][j] = nodeContent(a)
      a=a-1
    --print("i: " .. i ..  "  j: " .. j )
    until (j==1+i and j+i<n+1) or (j==i and j+i>n+1) or (i+j==n+1)
    tmp=-dir[2]
    dir[2]= dir[1]
    dir[1]=tmp
  until a<1
  return myTable
end

function printTable(myTable,n,printFunction)
  doubleBackslash="\\\\"
  for i=1,n do
    str=""
    for j=1,n do
      str= str .. myTable[j][i] .. " & "
    end
    str=string.gsub(str, "& $", doubleBackslash)
    printFunction(str)
  end
end

n=10
myTable=table(n)

--printTable(myTable,n,print) -- debug prints to console 
--printTable(myTable,n,tex.print) -- what we'll call the function as
```

### The `LaTeX`

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\directlua{dofile("makeMatrix.lua")}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  crossed/.style=
  {
    fill=blue!30!black,
    fill opacity=.4,
    text opacity=1,
  },
  square matrix/.style=
  {
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes=
    {
      draw=gray,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1cm
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (myMatrix)
  [
    square matrix,
  ]
  {
    \directlua{printTable(myTable,n,tex.print)}
  };

  \draw [very thick, red]
    (myMatrix-1-1.north west)
      -| ++(10,-10)
      -| ++(-10,9)
    foreach \x in {8,6,...,1}
    {
      -| ++(\x+1,-\x)
      -| ++(-\x,\x-1)
    }
    -- ++(1,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot 1.....

Comment: Yeah. I wondered about 1, but ruled against including it, per the convention I was taught at school. The list is hardwired in `myListCrossed` in the Lua file if change is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using Tikz is

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Container/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick, minimum size=1cm},
    XcrossBox/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=1cm,thick},
    LeftStrikeBox/.style={strike out, rotate=90, draw=black, minimum size=1cm,thick},
    RightStrikeBox/.style={strike out, draw=black, minimum size=1cm,thick},
    box/.style={rectangle,draw=white,fill=white, minimum size=.3cm},
    ]
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}
        \node[Container] at (\x,\y){};
    }
    \node[XcrossBox] at (5,5) {};  
    \node[box] at (5,5){5};  
    \node[LeftStrikeBox] at (4,4) {};
    \node[box] at (4,4){8};
    \node[RightStrikeBox] at (2,2) {};
    \node[box] at (2,2){6};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is 
[image]

Filling the rest is simple I presume.

Comment: If you want to complete the matrix, [I put its content here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ec7210093bda9b98ea56e846225e6a13)